# Equals statement being valid for both uppercase and lowercase of the same letter

Tags: java, char, ascii, equals

Having `var toCheck = a`

In this case `if(toCheck == 'a')` returns `true`

Is there a shorter/better way that this operation returns true for `A` also?\

Something different of `if(toCheck == 'a' || toCheck == 'A')`

Comment: `if(toCheck.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))`

Comment: @bakero that would not compile.

Comment: Unless things have changed in Java 10+, `==` is the wrong operator to use for string equality.

Comment: @Powerlord `char` is still a type.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch There's no indication of what type `toCheck` is since it doesn't reference a constant value.  `'a'` would be a constant value, but `a` alone is not.

Comment: @Powerlord There's at least one typo in the question. `if(toCheck == 'a' || toCheck == 'A')` looks like properly comparing equality on `char` literals to me.

Comment: I think there is no reason to shorten something like this. If one wants to use it multiple times, then they should convert the check to a function or macro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since *starting* with a *character*, [Character.toLowerCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase-char-) might be suitable.

> Converts the character argument to lowercase using case mapping information from the UnicodeData file ..

```
if (Character.toLowerCase(toCheck) == 'a') return true;
```

Or, conversely as Elliott points out:

```
if (Character.toUpperCase(toCheck) == 'A') return true;
```

Comment: Could also use `Character.toUpperCase(toCheck) == 'A'`

Answer (score 2):

If you’re only expecting characters that are in the “normal” range (single byte - ie ASCII):

```
if ((toChar & ~32) == 'A')
```

The only difference between

- `'a'`: `01100001`
- `'A'`: `01000001`

is bit 5 is on, and since 2<sup>5</sup> is `32`, ANDing with the negated (flip all bits) of `32` masks off all but bit 5, turning `'a'` into `'A'`.

Comment: This is so cryptic and low-level dirty/intimate - love it! .. and I'd still ask for an update in most code-review situations :}